# Formula to create range of 2 columns and unlimited rows

Tags: google-sheets

How to create in gsheet a range of two columns and unlimited rows with the next data:

- first column: non-empty rows A2:A from another sheet in current spreadsheet
- second column: constant string

So it could look like:

```
Data  | Const value 
----------------------
A2    | "Const string"
A3    | "Const string"
A4    | "Const string"
...
```

I'd like to use some kind of formula ({}, arrayformula, query) and not to write a gscript app for that

The reason i want it be a formula is that after A2:A should come B2:B with another const string; then come C2:C and so on

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your requirement but given what I understand to be your inputs ( I **assume** in `Sheet1`) and the output required, suggest trying:

```
=split(arrayformula(query(Sheet1!A1:A,"where A is not null")&"#Const string"),"#")
```

Requires copying down to suit but is not *unlimited* due to inherent Sheets constraints.

Comment: I guess arrayformula() is not working together with query() as these are two different concepts.

Comment: I tried your solution but instead of creating a range with a formula in the top-left corner, it created a single row